# Can I make this method more generic/smaller? (DRY)

Tags: c#, generics

I have already defined classes with names `Task` and `Person` both derived from `TimeStamp`.
I am maintaining a list of their respective timestamps.
as follows:

```
    public static List<TimeStamp> PeopleTS = new List<TimeStamp>();
    public static List<TimeStamp> TasksTS = new List<TimeStamp>();
```

I also have some generic functions such as below. but they have explicit check like `if (typeof(T) == typeof(Person))`

```
    public static bool AddObjects<T>(IEnumerable<T> Objects)
    {
        using (SQLiteTransaction mytransaction = grindDBConnection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(grindDBConnection))
            {
                mycommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [" + typeof(T).Name.Pluralize().ToLower() + "] ("
                    + CommaSeperatedColumnName<T>()
                    + ") VALUES ("
                    + ParameterizedCommaSeparatedColumnName<T>()
                    + ")";

                AddParameterstoSqlCommand<T>(mycommand.Parameters);
                foreach (T obj in Objects)
                {
                    BuildParametersofSqlCommand<T>(mycommand.Parameters, obj);
                    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Person))//Can I do away with this check?
                        PeopleTS.Add((TimeStamp)(object)obj);
                    else
                        TasksTS.Add((TimeStamp)(object)obj);
                }
            }
            mytransaction.Commit();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Can I make some changes so that I can directly modify the corresponding list on the basis of T? Something like:

```
    public static List<TimeStamp> TS<Person> = new List<TimeStamp>();
    public static List<TimeStamp> TS<Task> = new List<TimeStamp>();
```

Above two lines of code is just an example. it doesn't compile.
So I can modify any of the above List With `TS<T>` where T:Person,Task.
Or what I have got is the best Solution so far.
Complete code is available at  [Grind / GrindClient / Grind.Common / Cache.cs](https://bitbucket.org/AEonAX/grind/src/8b404f7c4839055d35e30dad24f36ad08f95a672/GrindClient/Grind.Common/Cache.cs?at=master)

**Update:**
Currently I am using this two lists to check if I have latest Tasks/People from cache or retrieve them from server. I can retrieve timestamps of Task/Person from server. I only retrieve complete data if I don't have or I have stale data in cache.

Comment: Just wondering: Why do you have 2 separate lists for them? We need to see more context to understand what you're doing!

Comment: you can use entity framework. it would certainly be shorter and more generic.

Comment: @DarthVader I am using ActiveRecord in Ruby(Sinatra) Server. On Client Side I "used" NDatabase to store my .NET Objects. Then I migrated to SQLite. Can you point me in right direction so as to use Entity Framework. Some links atleast. Google gives abundant results but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a static class to hold your items and make compiler figure out which one to use. This will make your `static List<TimeStamp>` fields go away.

```
public static class TimeStampCollection<T> where T : TimeStamp
{
    public static List<TimeStamp> Items = new List<TimeStamp>();
}
```

And in your method:

```
            foreach (T obj in Objects)
            {
                BuildParametersofSqlCommand<T>(mycommand.Parameters, obj);
                mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                TimeStampCollection<T>.Items.Add((TimeStamp)(object)obj);
            }
```

Later on whenever you reference `PeopleTS` you'd use `TimeStampCollection<Person>.Items`.

Bad to be honest, the rest of your method is not pretty either, and the change you're trying to make is something I would be least concerned about. Hand crafting SQL query as a string? Not cool.

Comment: I am learning things. And you just taught me something new. Thanks for that. Can you explain `Hand crafting SQL query as a string? Not Cool`. Or point me in some direction so as to not hand craft the SQL query.

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on SQL Injection Attacks, and how to build parameterized queries in C#. Then you'll immediately see what's not cool! Best of luck. :)

Comment: Yes I knew about that I am using parameterized queries as well. You can see here https://bitbucket.org/AEonAX/grind/src/8b404f7c4839055d35e30dad24f36ad08f95a672/GrindClient/Grind.Common/Cache.cs?at=master especially BuildParametersofSqlCommand it fills the parameters from object using reflection